# See anything wrong with my attempt to get Flask running? (mod_wsgi + virtualenv)

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi, virtualenv, flask

I have a VPS running a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I'm trying to set up a live application using the Flask microframework, but it's giving me trouble. I took notes while I tried to get it running and here's my play-by-play in an effort to pinpoint exactly where I went wrong.

## INSTALLATION

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/#installation

```
$ adduser myapp
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install virtualenv

/home/myapp/
-- www/

$ sudo pip install virtualenv

/home/myapp/
-- www/
-- env/

$ . env/bin/activate
$ easy_install Flask
```

## MOD_WSGI

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

## Creating WSGI file

```
$ nano /home/myapp/www/myapp.wsgi

--myapp.wsgi contents:--------------------------
activate_this = '/home/myapp/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
from myapp import app as application

/home/myapp/
-- www/
     -- myapp.wsgi
-- env/
```

## Configuring Apache

```
$ nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.com

-----myapp.com file contents ---------------------
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=myapp group=myapp threads=5 python-path=/home/myapp/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myapp/www/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory /home/myapp/www>
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

## Enable the virtual host file I just created

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
$ ln -s ../sites-available/myapp.com
```

## Restart Apache

```
$ /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Servers me a 500 server error page. Here's the latest error log:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=3514): Target WSGI script '/home/myapp/www/myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=3514): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/myapp/www/myapp.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myapp/www/myapp.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
from myapp import app as application
ImportError: No module named myapp
```

The errors allude that it's something strikingly obvious, but I'm quite lost.

Comment: By the way, did you know about the command `cat`? It prints out the contents of a file (so in this log it would produce what you've copied out of `nano` automatically)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obviously, it cannot find your "`myapp`" package. You should add it to the path in your `myapp.wsgi` file like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(DIRECTORY_WHERE_YOUR_PACKAGE_IS_LOCATED)
from myapp import app
```

Also, if `myapp` module is a package, you should put and empty `__init__.py` file into its directory.

Answer (score 0):

Edit line `sys.path.append`, it needs to be a string.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('directory/where/package/is/located')
```

**Notice** the single quotes.